# Dockerfile CMD not executing a bash script

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, docker-build

Dockerfile CMD not executing a bash script as expected e.g. the echo commands in `set-env.sh` do not get executed.

First, I pass in an env var to the image for Dockerfile to use

`docker build -f Dockerfile --pull --build-arg env=prod -t test-app .`

Here's the **Dockerfile** I'm using

```
# Multi-stage
# 1) Node image for building frontend assets
# 2) nginx stage to serve frontend assets

# Name the node stage "builder"
FROM node:16 AS builder
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /project
# Copy all files from current directory to working dir in image
COPY . .
# install node modules and build assets
RUN yarn install --network-timeout 100000 && yarn build

# nginx state for serving content
FROM nginx:alpine

# Nginx config
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY conf /etc/nginx

# Set working directory to nginx asset directory
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
# Remove default nginx static assets
RUN rm -rf ./*
# Copy static assets from builder stage
COPY --from=builder /project/build .

# Set enviorment so the set-env.sh script can read the correct env file
ARG env
ENV ENVIRONMENT=$env

# these statements print out the env vars as expected during the build
RUN echo $env
RUN echo $ENVIRONMENT

# Default port exposure
EXPOSE 443

# Copy environment file and script into container
COPY ./set-env.sh .

# Add bash
RUN apk add --no-cache bash

# Containers run nginx with global directives and daemon off
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/share/nginx/html/set-env.sh && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

**set-env.sh** (referenced in the last `Dockerfile` line above)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Recreate config file
rm -rf ./env-config.js
touch ./env-config.js

# Choose the .env file base on "ENV" defined in the DockerFile
if [ $env == "dev" ]; then
  echo "TEST: DEV " >> ./env-config.js
elif [ $env == "prod" ]; then
  echo "TEST: PROD " >> ./env-config.js
else
  echo "Unsupported environment"
  exit 1
fi
```

Above does NOT echo anything out to `env-config.js` - not sure why.

However, whenever I run `set-env.sh` manually from within the container, it works as expected e.g. prints out DEV or PROD test line to `env-config.js` based on the env param passed in to the docker build command

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Dockerfile, you set the variable `ENVIRONMENT` but in your script, you test on the variable `env`.

Build argument variables are not passed on as environment variables, so you can't use `env` without setting it in the Dockerfile.

Either change

```
ENV ENVIRONMENT=$env
```

to

```
ENV env=$env
```

in the Dockerfile ***or*** change your script `if` statements to

```
if [ $ENVIRONMENT == "dev" ]; then
  echo "TEST: DEV " >> ./env-config.js
elif [ $ENVIRONMENT == "prod" ]; then
  echo "TEST: PROD " >> ./env-config.js
else
  echo "Unsupported environment"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Better to use `=` rather than `==` -- that way one's statements work just as well with a baseline-standard `[` (at least when extra quoting is added) and one isn't creating bash-only finger memory. Alternately, consider `case $ENVIRONMENT in dev) echo "TEST: DEV";; prod) echo "TEST: PROD";; *) echo "Unsupported environment" >&2; exit 1;; esac >>./env-config.js`, which doesn't require any bash extensions at all.

Comment: (I was also going to suggest in the question changing the shebang line to `#!/bin/sh` and not installing bash in the Dockerfile; this doesn't really seem to use any bash features.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the info posted by everyone.

The issue was related to how I was testing the script. I ran the following and  logged in into the container to check on what actually happened.

`docker run test-app tail -F asdflg`

Unbeknown to me, the tail command, while allowing the container to run, actually seemed to hold up the processing of the CMD on the last line of my Dockerfile... Once I ran the container with `docker compose up` instead, everything worked as expected.